# Value is tryin to be set on a copy of a slice from DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

I´m doing some stuff with pandas and python. I have the next code

```
df = pd.read_csv("Request.csv", keep_default_na=False)
df1 = df.loc[(df["Request Status"] == "Closed")]
df1["Request Close-Down Actual"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Request Close-Down Actual"], errors = 'coerce' )
df3 = df1.loc[(df1["Request Close-Down Actual"] < '2016-11-01') | (df1["Request Close-Down Actual"].isnull())]        
df3.set_index("Request ID", inplace = True)
df3.to_csv("Request1.csv")
```

The issue is when i run the code i receive the next issue

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> df1.loc["Request Close-Down Actual"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Request
> Close-Down Actual"], errors = 'coerce' )

Can someone give me a hand with this please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it and for me it works nice.

Problem should be in row above:

```
df1 = df.loc[(df["Request Status"] == "Closed")]
```

And solution is [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
#loc is not necessary
df1 = df[df["Request Status"] == "Closed"].copy()
```

---

Error show `loc` - try remove it if need select column:

```
df1.loc["Request Close-Down Actual"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Request Close-Down Actual"], errors = 'coerce' )
```

to:

```
df1["Request Close-Down Actual"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Request Close-Down Actual"], errors = 'coerce' )
```

Comment: Working perfectly now. Thank you very much