# How to set value to a cell filtered by rows in python DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],columns=['A','B','C'])
df[df['B']%2 ==0]['C'] = 5
```

I am expecting this code to change the value of columns C to 5, wherever B is even. But it is not working.

It returns the table as follow

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3   10  11  12
```

I am expecting it to return

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   5
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   5
3   10  11  12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If need change value of column in `DataFrame` is necessary [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with condition and column name:

```
df.loc[df['B']%2 ==0, 'C'] = 5
print (df)
    A   B   C
0   1   2   5
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   5
3  10  11  12
```

Your solution is nice example of chained indexing - [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).

Comment: Hi @jezrael, this approach doesn't work for me, as `pandas` changed its behavior according to this page: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: @garciparedes - It is another problem, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027229/value-is-tryin-to-be-set-on-a-copy-of-a-slice-from-df/42027248#42027248)

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the order to:

```
df['C'][df['B']%2 == 0] = 5
```

And it also works

Comment: Rather not, because warning - [check this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters)

Comment: tnx :) but running this code doesn't produce a warning. maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy where

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['B']%2 == 0, 5, df['C'])
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   5
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   5
3   10  11  12
```